# R multiplot combining base and lattice graphs

Tags: r, plot, visualization, lattice

I produced various graphs using base R and plotted these together with the layout function. Now of course this system doesn't work if I'm upgrading some of them to lattice (aka combine base and lattice plot).
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you considered using the `ggplot2` package? It allows you to create lattice plots, facet_wraps, and facet_grids to plot multiple graphs with the same axis.

Comment: Yes quite few times but plots with many low level elements are (on my knowledge) really indigested on ggplot